# How to dispatch jsp from memory java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, dispatch

I am trying to find a way to dispatch jsp/html from memory.

Now I am using the getRequestDispatcher method and passing it the path of my local project.

What I am doing now:

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/test/update.jsp").forward(request, 
     response);
```

I want to make the code better and upload the updated file from s3 and not locally in my project.
I would be happy for some help!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to set the s3 file in the request and forward it?

Comment: I want to take the file from s3 do changes to the file and open the file.